# How to get the file name of a PIL image?

Tags: python, image

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("pic_1.png")
print(img.filename) #pic_1.png
#actual outcome:
#AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'get_filename'
```

I'm working on Python 3.8.

Comment: Why would you not store the string in a variable at the beginning and then do Image.open(theImage) and then you can just use that variable later on

Comment: Hello Luke, I'm sending the PIL image to a server socket as an echo. I don't want to send the file's name, therefore when I get the file back I would like to extract it's name file.

Comment: @Maya probably when image is serialized via `pickle.dumps(...)` its filename attribute is removed. Therefore you have to send tuple `(img.filename, img)` to server.

Comment: So you aren't sending the name of the file to the server with the image but you expect the server to send it back to you?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Looks like Maya is sending just pickled `img` to server. I checked that `img` has valid attribute `.filename` before pickling, but after pickling+unpickling this attribute disappears, only image RGB data remains, so PIL doesn't pickle some of attributes like filename.